# Sort And Order In React-Query and useInfiniteQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, frontend, react-query

I'm using it with a mock server (simple Express), so I want to change the order of the data (with loadMore) , but it is not changing the order of the pages:

Senario:

- Click the header to change the order
- After the sort change, we will refetch the data
- We need to have the sort ability with and without loadMore

**Update:** see the screenshot below.

[image]

```
export function useGetDocumentDesignRevisionsQuery(
  designName: string,
  options: Options,
) {
  const { limit, sort } = options

  const fetchRevisions = ({ pageParam = 0 }) => {
    return DesignManagerApi.getDocumentDesignRevisions(designName, {
      offset: pageParam,
      limit,
      sort,
    })
  }

  const normalizeResultData = (data: ReturnedData) => {
    return {
      pages: [...data.pages],
      pageParams: [...data.pageParams],
    }
  }

  return useInfiniteQuery(['documentDesignRevisions', designName], fetchRevisions, {
    select: normalizeResultData,
  })
}
```

```
const [sortedBy, setSortedBy] = useState<SortedBy>({
    order: 'desc',
    key: 'lastUpdatedAt',
  })

 const getDocumentDesignRevisionsQuery = useGetDocumentDesignRevisionsQuery(
    designName,
    {
      limit: REVISIONS_LIST_LIMIT,
      sort: (sortedBy.order === 'desc' ? '-' : '') + sortedBy.key,
    },
  )

function loadMoreRevisions() {
    getDocumentDesignRevisionsQuery.fetchNextPage({
      pageParam: SOME_NUMBER, // offset
    })
  }

const sortItems = (info: SortedBy) => {
    setSortedBy({
      key: info.key,
      order: info.order === 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getDocumentDesignRevisionsQuery.refetch()
  }, [sortedBy])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not making effective use of your query key. In order to know that you expect a different dataset when you update your sort (or your limit for that matter..) you need to make it part of the query key. The query key needs to uniquely (with the exception of the pageParam for infinite queries) coincide with the response datasets you get from the API. I would suggest the following refactor..

```js
const fetchRevisions = ({ 
    queryKey: [queryType, designName, options], 
    pageParam = 0 
  }) => {
    const { limit, sort } = options;
    return DesignManagerApi.getDocumentDesignRevisions(
      designName, 
      {
        offset: pageParam,
        limit,
        sort,
      }
    );
}

const normalizeResultData = (data: ReturnedData) => {
  return {
    pages: [...data.pages],
    pageParams: [...data.pageParams],
  }
}

export function useGetDocumentDesignRevisionsQuery(
  designName: string,
  options: Options,
) {
  return useInfiniteQuery(['documentDesignRevisions', designName, options], fetchRevisions, {
    select: normalizeResultData,
  })
}
```

Comment: I've added your changes but no luck, you can see the screenshot above.

Comment: Can you provide a small gist or code sandbox to demonstrate the issue, the code above is equivalent to what I'm using in my production code.

Comment: I've solved it by changing the backend (mock-server) to send the last data on sort (descending)

Comment: So once you corrected the issue with the key you relized that your mock backend wasn't respecting the sort?

Comment: No, the main problem was with the mock-server